# Getting duplicate rows when querying Cloud SQL in AppMaker

Tags: google-cloud-sql, google-app-maker

I migrated from Drive tables to a 2nd gen MySQL Google Cloud SQL data model.  I was able to insert 19 rows into the following Question table in AppMaker:

```
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field             | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| SurveyType        | varchar(64)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| QuestionNumber    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| QuestionType      | varchar(64)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Question          | varchar(512) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| SecondaryQuestion | varchar(512) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I queried the data from the command line and know it is good.  However, when I query the data in AppMaker like this:

```
var newQuery = app.models.Question.newQuery();
newQuery.filters.SurveyType._equals = surveyType;
newQuery.sorting.QuestionNumber._ascending();  
var allRecs = newQuery.run();
```

I get 19 rows with the same data (the first row) instead of the 19 different rows.  Any idea what is wrong?  Additionally (and possibly related) my list rows in AppMaker are not showing any data.  I did notice that _key is not being set correctly in the records.

(Edit: I thought maybe having two columns as the primary key was the problem, but I tried having the PK be a single identity column, same result.)

Thanks for any tips or pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by creating the table inside AppMaker rather than using a table created directly in the Cloud Shell.  Not sure if existing tables are not supported or if there is a bug in AppMaker, but since it is working I am closing this.

Answer (score 0):

You have two primary key fields in your table, which is problematic according to the App Maker Cloud SQL documentation:  https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/cloudsql

> **App Maker can only write to tables that have a single primary key**
>   **field**—If you have an existing Google Cloud SQL table with zero or
>   multiple primary keys, you can still query it in App Maker, but you
>   can't write to it.

This may account for the inability of the view to be able to properly display each row and to properly set the _key.

Comment: Sorry, did not see your answer until after I edited my question.  I did suspect that but I get the same result with a single column as PK.  Also, I was (strangely) able to write to the table fine with two columns as PK, it was just the reading that is the problem.

Comment: Does the table work correctly in App Maker when you create a Page and Table widget and don't use a the Query (just point to the SQL table as a datasource)?

Comment: Also, when you say, "when I query the data in AppMaker", where is the query being done, on a page or the Model's Datasource Query?

Comment: Well, creating a test table produces the same results because the same query script is being called.  Obviously it is done in the datasource's query.